# Can HTML5 and Javascript be used to automatically download and install binary file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, installation, binary

Are you able to download a specific file from the server and save it into a specific directory. Keep in mind that it needs to work with binary files. I want to install a file into a Program Files directory. If this is not possible, is there a solution with Google Gears, Flash, Java, or Silverlight?

Comment: Sounds very dangerous...

Comment: You want to download and install this binary file without intervention from the user?  If so, then you're creating malware - good luck with that.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: The "why" is obvious, malware. The answer is no. And I can't say your kind is very welcome here...

Comment: Actually, this has nothing to do with malware. I can see how you might think that, however, what I am trying to do is enable easy realmlist and custom patch installation for WoW (which are binaries). This is simply for a WoW private server, in that players do not have to go through the hassle of setting the game up manually. I don't need flame wars, I just need answers.

Comment: @swanboy this isn't really trying to be a flamewar... the answer is "No, you cannot do that."  The reasons why you cannot do it are manifest, but foremost is the security concern that is mentioned here *ad nauseam*.  The details you've provided in this comment should have went in your original post, that way people wouldn't react so strongly.  Look at it objectively; it should be obvious why you go the response you did. That aside, you did get your answer... "No". You should accept one of the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. It would be a great security issue.

You can create a simple download link, and let the user specify where he saves the file. If you ask him to do that, he might even execute your installer if he wishes to.

Flash and the others are not allowed to do things like this as well. Imagine what a huge problem would that mean...

Comment: @LeTruffle What do you mean? Can you show an example? You could even post in the form of an answer.

Answer (score 2):

No. This should not be possible. It would be a great security hole.

Answer (score 0):

You  can not do that with JS and HTML

Answer (score 0):

An HTML5 page, using the storage API, can use local storage to save data in any format but this does not, nor should it, interact directly with the client's host file system.  The only mechanisms that I have found to read files from the host file system is to use a file input control.  In order to do what you are asking, this will have to be handled as a download and must require user intervention.